# Is it possible to make divs of varying height wrap and vertically align top to bottom with CSS?

Tags: html, css

The divs wrap in the image below, but the 5th item won't break the horizontal of the bottom of 1st item to align with the bottom of the 2nd, leaving an unnecessary space.

Is there any way to get around this without having to manually break the page into a set number of columns?

[image: Divs wrapping but not aligning top]

Thanks!

Comment: Ehm, what are you doing exactly to get this result?

Comment: It's just `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: The answer is **no**.

Comment: @connexo Any suggested workarounds? Or is set columns with potential javascript adjustment of number of columns based on screen-size the most viable?

Comment: You can base the number of *CSS columns* on media queries. The downside is that it requires reordering the divs.

Comment: Cool, thanks. So I guess I could write some js to do that? Google+ seems to do something like that?

Comment: @Laser Check this fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/tQANc/

Comment: @CodeRomeos Thanks for the suggestion :) I think that's a manual implementation though, which requires setting both columns and heights–which doesn't help for automatically adjusting columns to screen size and adding content dynamically.

Comment: You can use the Masonry JS library to get the desired result.

Comment: @KevinHufnagl thanks, that's what I was looking for :)